# Cocoapods "Pod Update" - exception

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

I trying to perform pod update and I'm getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
12: from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.9.3/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' 11: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in` activate_bin_path'
10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `synchronize' 9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:304:in` block in activate_bin_path'
8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate' 7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in` activate_dependencies'
6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each' 5: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1452:in` block in activate_dependencies'
4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate' 3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in` activate_dependencies'
2: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each' 1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1449:in` block in activate_dependencies'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'CFPropertyList' (>= 2.3.3, < 4.0) among 81 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError) Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/ahinoammaoz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5:/Users/ahinoammaoz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.9.3/libexec', execute` gem env` for more information

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 8):

if you notice at the very end of your comment you are missing `'CFPropertyList' (>= 2.3.3, < 4.0) among 81 total gem(s)` I fixed mine my reinstalling cocoapods `sudo gem install cocoapods`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This fixed part of the issue. i needed to install also ffi (gem install ffi)

Comment: I installed with `brew install cocoapods`. It did not fix this issue for me. Not sure why.

Comment: I did `brew reinstall cocoapods` and then `brew link cocoapods` and the `sudo gem install cocoapods` and it all worked for me

Answer (score 0):

On the top of Roberto's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64271646/8988448, if you are using **react-native** please make sure to delete the node_modules and re-install them. Please follow the below steps.

- `sudo gem install cocoapods`
- `rm Podfile.lock`
- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `yarn install`
- `cd ios & pod install`